# ftp command times out in 18.04

Tags: server, upgrade, backup, deja-dup

I recently upgraded my server from 16.04 to 18.04. I have alway's used the command `ftp://backups@192.168.1.x/` in Deja Dup on my laptop (also recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 from 17.10)to make backups to the server but since the server upgrade that command would no longer work. After playing around I got the follow command to work `ftp://192.168.1.x/home/backups`

Why doesn't the original command `ftp://backups@192.168.1.x/` work any more in 18.04?

Comment: What do you mean that it doesn't work?  Could you please tell us the output of the command?  What's the IP of the machine now?  `ip a` should tell you your IP.  You need to use the correct IP in the command.  Did you ever connect from 18.04  -> 16.04 and it worked?

Comment: The command is in the storage configuration for the Backup GUI in Ubuntu, which I understand is based on Deja Dup. The GUI times out saying that backups@192.168.1.x/ cannot be reached. If I try from the command line the same thing happens. The IP is the correct IP as I can connect via ssh and also via Nautilus using the command `ftp://192.168.1.x/home/backups`. Which is why I changed the command in the Backups GUI, and that works. I have used the command `ftp://backups@192.168.1.x/` for years now and it has always worked until this last upgrade.