# difference between similar ftp commands

Tags: ftp

The following two commands seem to achieve the same result

- `ftp://directory@192.168.1.x/`
- `ftp://192.168.1.x/home/directory`

What is the difference between the commands

Comment: This might be the more objective question asked by OP than the former: [ftp command times out in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1083542/37165).

Comment: @clearkimura The question you mentioned never received an answer. This one received an answer which I accepted. What is the purpose of your comment? Should I remove one of the questions?

Comment: My comment was intended to hint reviewers, based on my review of two similar questions by OP. Then again, I overlooked that this question has been answered. Not sure why this question, being more objective, was voted to close more than the former, so I left a comment and skipped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The first command connects to default directory on server 192.168.1.x with username directory. You just need to type in your password.
- The second command connects to server 192.168.1.x to directory /home/directory. Username is not specified, so you need to provide username and password, after connecting.

Ftp server properties determine, which is root directory or default directory when loggin on. So the first command goes to the directory, which is specified as default per user. The second command goes to home/directory relative to root directory defined in ftp server.